# Can One Decrease Overall Accuracy in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a program to calculate primes, and I look at the remainder of the possible prime I'm testing and all the primes I have so far, but stop if I get to the point where I am comparing the PossPrime to anything above its square root. (I can explain this if needed).  I don't care about any digits after the decimal point of the sqrt; is there a way to tell Python not to bother calculating those?

And, is there a way to integrate that aspect (only testing the primes under it until I get to the sqrt) into the `for` loop?

```
  #There's some boring setup before here that isn't problematic.
while True:
    PossWasDivis = False  #initialize the var (used to convey if the possible prime was divis)

    sqrtP = int(sqrt(PossPrime))
    for iterationOfArray in range(2, sqrtP):

       # print ("Comparing: (", PossPrime, "% (", GlobPrimeList [iterationOfArray],")) == 0")
        if (PossPrime % (GlobPrimeList [iterationOfArray])) == 0:
       #     print(PossPrime, "was divisable by", GlobPrimeList[iterationOfArray],"!  Breaking for loop")
            PossWasDivis = True
            break
        if (GlobPrimeList [iterationOfArray]) > sqrtP:
            break

    if PossWasDivis == False:    # Occurs when none of the tested #s are divis
        GlobPrimeList.append (PossPrime)
        f.write(str(PossPrime)+'\n')

    #Switch between incramenting PossPrime between 2 and 4
    if PossPrimeStat == 2:
        PossPrimeStat = 4
        PossPrime += 4
    else:                 # if PossPrimeStat == 4:
        PossPrimeStat = 2
        PossPrime += 2
```

The GlobPrimeList has some primes preloaded in it to start out with and continues finding more indefinitely until I cancel the program.

Comment: 1. No, why would there be a function to calculate an integer-only square root? 2. What do you mean? That's already what you `for` loop over.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the loop time will dominate the sqrt. That being said, with a more imperative style it is sometimes inverted and expressed as: `i * i < x`

Comment: 1. Just asking; 2. So the sqrtP in the `for` loop gets used as the highest the `iterationOfArray` will go, but I want the loop to go until the value in the list (GlobPrimeList) _pointed to_ by `iterationOfArray` is greater than the possible prime.

Comment: Come again, user2864740?  I'm pretty new to python; most of that went over my head.

Comment: @user3743372 still not clear what you mean. Is this supposed to be a prime sieve? Also, you should read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008

Comment: Thanks for the link to the py style guide, but in the interest of time, if there's a specific part of it that I should read now, it'd be nice to know.  The GlobPrimeList has some primes preloaded in it and continues finding more until I cancel the program.

Comment: @jonrsharpe There are quite a few very useful applications for an integer square root algorithm, and several such algorithms exist. Of course, you're right that this isn't necessarily one of them - a simple `floor(sqrt(...))` would suffice here since, if it's done right, it should only be calculated once anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't care about any digits after the decimal point of the sqrt; is there a way to tell Python not to bother calculating those?

Nope.

`math.sqrt()` works with floating-point values.  The precision you get is baked right in to the math.

Python does contain functions for "arbitrary-precision" math, where you can specify how much precision you will get... but those functions are much slower than the functions that operate on float values.  If you want faster code, you will be using float values, and there is no way to tell Python not compute the whole value.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could upvote that (I just made my profile here)!  Do you have any insight for figuring out how to make the top # of the range (in the `for` loop) be the indexOfArray that points to the # in the array that's > the sqrtP, though?

Comment: Perhaps you should study this: a web page showing different ways to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  This link points straight to a Python function that uses a list.  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Using_array_lookup

Comment: I don't get how `is_prime = [False] * 2 + [True] * (limit - 1)` in the link works and is implemented in `if is_prime[n]:`.  It looks like the first one put two falses and however many trues into the is_prime list, but I don't get how that's useful later.

Comment: When the function is done running, that will be a list of true/false flags, where True means a number is prime.  The function starts out with a false for position 0 and position 1, but for positions 2 through the end it starts out with true flags.  Then it starts finding true flags and "crossing out" multiples (marking them false).  It finds 2 and crosses out 4, 6, 8, 10, and so on; finds 3 and crosses out 6, 9, 12, 15, and so on; finds 5 and crosses out 10, 15, 20, 25, and so on; you get the idea.  Then at the end it looks at the true flags to find which numbers were prime, and makes a list.